Removing a snapshot from a QCOW2 image on the fly
Is that possible to delete a snapshot from a QCOW2 image without shutting down a virtual machine (QEMU+KVM)? Wouldn't running qemu-img snapshot -d ... break data consistency? If so, would that break consistency if one runs virsh pause ... before deleting a snapshot and then runs virsh resume ...? What do you think?
Thanks!

When using libvirt, altering a qcow2 image via any tool outside virsh cli might and probably will corrupt the qcow2 image!
qemu-img should only be used for images that are not in use (by another process or a running VM)
To remove a snapshot from a running VM you can use the following procedure:
List all snapshots:
virsh snapshot-list <vm_name>

Remove a snapshot:
virsh snapshot-delete <vm_name> <snapshot_name>


Thank you. I totally forgotten about virsh snapshot-delete ..., sorry. :-)
